# How to get the path for a view

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I am looking for a way to get the PATH for a view and use it in a href.
For the rest of the links in my .tpl files i use something simillar to:

```
print url('node/36');
```

How can i mimic this behaviour for the views module? I want to be able to edit the path for the view from the admin interface without requiring to modify the theme.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi mate,

I think its may help you ..

$view = views_get_view($view_name, TRUE);
$view->display['page']->display_options['path'] = $new_path;
views_save_view($view);

this code for get a view and set a new path, but you need now to build a form to create interface ...

Comment: i already set it in admin so i just needed $view = views_get_view($view_name, TRUE); ur($view->display['page']->display_options['path']); . thanks a lot, post it as a separate answer so i can mark it as checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit view path by php code:

```
 $view = views_get_view($view_name, TRUE);
 $view->display['page']->display_options['path'] = $new_path;
 views_save_view($view);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function get_path() {
  if (!empty($this->override_path)) {
    return $this->override_path;   
  }

  if (empty($this->display_handler)) {
    if (!$this->set_display('default')) {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }   
  return $this->display_handler->get_path(); 
}
```